# Problem mounting CIFS VFS via fstab at boot

Tags: boot, mount, raspbian, fstab, cifs

I'm running Raspbian Jessie on a freshly installed Raspberry Pi Model B+. I used `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` some hours ago, the system should be up to date.
I'm trying to mount a USB disk which is connected to my AVM Fritz!Box. To do so I added this to my /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.178.1/FRITZ.NAS/VBTM-Store-n-Go-01 /home/pi/fb cifs username=myuser,password=mypass,workgroup=WORKGROUP,users,auto,user_xattr 0 0
```

After rebooting the Raspberry Pi the USB disk is not mounted to my /home/pi/fb directory.

A `sudo mount -a` resolves this problem immediately and I'm able to access the USB disk.

I had a look with `dmesg` and found several entries marked red. Some of them seem to address this issue:

```
[    3.774312] systemd[1]: Job kbd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start  
[    3.868534] systemd[1]: Job raspi-config.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start  
[    3.964346] systemd[1]: Job console-setup.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start  
[   14.979342] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.  
[   14.979767] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101  
[   18.085217] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.  
[   18.087841] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101  
[   18.997658] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unknown ioctl 0x40187a22  
[   86.698592] CIFS VFS: Autodisabling the use of server inode numbers on \\192.168.178.1\FRITZ.NAS. This server doesn't seem to support them properly. Hardlinks will not be recognized on this mount. Consider mounting with the "noserverino" option to silence this message.
```

**Why is Raspbian ignoring the fstab on startup?**

Answer (score 1):

I added "noauto,x-systemd.automount" to my mount options in fstab like suggested by "DavidCWGA" here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/824

Working for me now!